# How to do something with a saved string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage where a user fills in textboxes, and I need to be able to see the info they fill in for review. I want to automatically send an email with the input value to myself, or save a text file with the input value to my computer, or anything that would let me view the information. I can't use php, so is there any way I can do this with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send emails using JavaScript, nor can you save to a file on your disk.  You can, however, open emails using "mailto:" links.

Example: `location = "mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=Test Email&body=Hello World";`

That will open the user's default client, if any, and pre-populate the subject and body.  The user still has to click "send".

If you want something like an email form, you need to post the form to server side code, and send emails from there.

While you can't create a file on the system, you CAN create files in JavaScript for downloading. Example:

HTML

```
<a href='#' download="file.txt" id='downloadlink'>Download</a>
```

JS

```
var blob = new Blob(["Text body."], { type: 'text/plain' });
if (url) URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
// REM: URL.revokeObjectURL(url); is needed to free the URL resource when no longer needed.
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.getElementById('downloadlink').href = url;
```

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zyogawLh/15/

Comment: does that file only appear on their computer? or can I see it too?

Comment: What do you mean "can I see it too"?  A blob (object) is created in JavaScript, that contains text, and you have access that blob (yes, and can read it [the object] also, if that's what you mean).  The file downloads like any other file downloaded from a web server - nothing special happens! It just gets saved to the user's computer, and you cannot, as normal, access that file. For more details see here: https://goo.gl/294xPW  (BTW, this only works on IE 10+ I believe)